# upload file from php in specific folder or mysql

Tags: php

I need to upload photo at register form, but i dont know how to do that in php. I wanna to store uploaded file in a specific folder or in mysql

Comment: [PHP manual: Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Answer (score 2):

The best I can say is please check the [PHP Manual on Handling File Uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

Start with a form like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="yourphp.php" method="POST">
    Choose Image: <input name="my_image" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

and in PHP, if a file is submitted, you can find details in `$_FILES['my_image']` in this case. Be sure to read the manual thoroughly for additional details and security measures.

If you need to store avatars, you can also try [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) that is used by StackOverflow as well AFAIK.